# React state updating unexpected

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a form with functionality where the user first views a list of days containing specific info about that day, can click a day, and then a unique form to edit info about that day appears as a modal. So the list is showing data from state, and the form shows that state as a defaultValue of inputs in the form. The form should have the functionality to save changes and to also cancel, which should close the form and forget any changes the user may have made.

The problem is that the form is displaying a value from state but when I press cancel, the changes I was in the middle of making still get sent to state, thereby updating the view of the list of days.

As a user I should expect to see the original data before I started editing, but what I'm seeing are the edits that I was making when I changed my mind.

here is a codeSandbox recreating the issue...
[codeSandbox recreating issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/yjv12z93yv)

This seems like very basic functionality, but yet I can't seem to find any information on it. Am I missing some basic React concept here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Props are passed by-ref in React. In your example, you're passing the `days` array all the way through to `Form.js`. On line 30 of `Forms.js`, you take the new value of the input field and store it in `days[...].shifts[...].message`, which changes the value in the **original state object** of the topmost component. Because this is done by mutating the state object and not by `setState`, the changes aren't seen until something else triggers a re-render of the topmost component, at which point the new values are shown in the button list.

One solution would be to store a temporary `message` state variable in the `Form` component and if the user clicks Submit, pass that current value back up as a parameter to `this.props.onSubmit` and let the top-level component use that value to update the `days` array properly (with a true state change as necessary).

Working example is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/9oqxlwol4o

Comment: I got that working like you said, but the only issue is that the real project I'm working on is using Material-UI, and the TextField components I'm using are controlled components - so this poses the issue where I need to initially display state as the value and also see the edits as I'm editing it, requiring the value to be linked to state and not a 'tempMessage' variable. Or am I missing something there?

Comment: Assuming your `Form` component mounts at the start of an edit (i.e. it is not always mounted, but mounts each time the user starts to edit something), you could have a `message` state variable with an initial value of whatever you're editing. This would be passed to the `value` of the input field, and the input's `onChange` would trigger a `setState` with a new value for `message`. When it comes time to "commit" the edit, pass the current value of `message` to a prop function and let a parent component actually make the change to the actual object.

Comment: Your goal in React should be to break things down to the smallest components possible, decoupling state and props and using events (i.e. functions passed as props) to relay data back up the tree of components.

Comment: ultimately, in the real project, I have to update a very nested state object. So I can't see how to avoid mutating the object and setting state directly. I tried to make a copy with Object.assign() but the original issue still persists.

Comment: Unfortunately you're going to have a plethora of problems when trying to use deeply nested states without having a layer of abstraction to handle passing the data back/forth. Breaking it apart into more layers of components can help, but you might need a different solution as well such as a manager layer, or some other utility to break apart the data before passing it into a component.

Comment: Never mind! I wasn't doing what you said: breaking things down into the smallest components possible. I wasn't initializing state in the form component specifically enough. I reconfigured the state object there, then in the onChange function I spread a copy of it, and then was able to directly set the values, thereby avoiding the mutating vs. setting state issue.